# I don't understand how creating a custom user works

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm reading the Django 3.2 documentation (custom authentication) and there are some lines of code that I can't understand.

I will try to read and explain what I can understand, or what I think I understand. Please correct me if I am wrong

Resource link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

#### Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

This method is used to create a standard user, it receives 2 main parameters: email and password.

```
def create_user(self, email, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

If the field is not of the email type, execute error:

```
if not email:
    raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
```

I dont understand; I know that the normalize_email method puts all text in lowercase. But I don't understand the self.model (): this is not a method, is it? Shouldn't it be like this: user.email = self.normalize_email (email)?

```
user = self.model(
    email=self.normalize_email(email),
)
```

The set_password method takes as an argument 'password' that the user entered, encrypts it and stores it in a structure or instance called user.

```
user.set_password(password)
```

The "save" method stores the record we have entered in the database. I have no idea how using = self._db works. Wouldn't it be enough to just call the save method? example user.save()

```
user.save(using=self._db)
```

create_superuser
This method creates an Admin, receives an email and a password. But I don't understand why you are referring to the create_user method.

```
user = self.create_user(...)
```

There is a line of code in the model that I don't understand its functionality either. Why instantiate the MyUserManager class in a variable called objects?

```
objects = MyUserManager()
```

Please explain me in an easy way